# modalpop is not working inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

in my webform.i have listview and a placeholder inside a update panel.i have to popup a window showing details of selected item.i am dynamically creating popup on listview item_command.
updatepanel has asynchronous trigger on listview item_command.

earlier i was using panel as modal popupwindow.i kept panel inside the update panel.i have to pass value to iframe.but the window was displaying but the iframe src was not displaying.so i created the window dynamically.

here is my code.

```
protected void OrderList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.CommandName)
     {
        case "ViewOrderDetails":
        ListViewDataItem currentItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        DataKey currentDataKey = this.OrderList.DataKeys[currentItem.DisplayIndex];
        string Orderid = Convert.ToString(currentDataKey["Order_Id"]);
        Createpopwindow(Orderid );
        Break;
     }
}

private void Createpopwindow(string contestid)
{
    popupholder.Controls.Clear();

    Panel popuppanel = new Panel();
    popuppanel.ID = "poppanel1";
    popuppanel.Width=550;
    popuppanel.CssClass = "Dialoguebox";

    HtmlGenericControl popupbody = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    ImageButton closebtn = new ImageButton();
    closebtn.ID="panelclose";
    closebtn.ImageUrl="~/images/close01.png";
    HtmlGenericControl frame = new HtmlGenericControl("iframe");
    frame.Attributes.Add("width","100%");
    frame.Attributes.Add("src", "joincontest.aspx?contest=" + contestid);

    popupbody.Controls.Add(closebtn);

    popuppanel.Controls.Add(popupbody);
    popuppanel.Controls.Add(frame);
    popupholder.Controls.Add(popuppanel);


    //creating modal popup extender

    ModalPopupExtender Popup = new ModalPopupExtender();
    Popup.ID = "popupextender";
    Popup.TargetControlID = "Button1";
    Popup.PopupControlID = "poppanel1";
    Popup.CancelControlID = "panelclose";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(Popup);

    Popup.Show();
}
```

but the popup is not showing on selecting the listview item.
did i missed any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are creating this dynamically, and not in your markup?
If you create your modalpopup in the markup, you can still set all the values dynamically, before you show it.